# SVN: svnserve.conf not limiting access

Tags: svn, authentication, repository

I want to allow only the users in my passwd file to have any access to my repository.  My svnserve.conf looks like the following:

```
### This file controls the configuration of the svnserve daemon, if you
### use it to allow access to this repository. (If you only allow
### access through http: and/or file: URLs, then this file is
### irrelevant.)

### Visit http://subversion.tigris.org/ for more information.

[general]
### These options control access to the repository for unauthenticated
### and authenticated users. Valid values are "write", "read",
### and "none". The sample settings below are the defaults.
anon-access = none
auth-access = write

realm = Sample Repository
password-db = passwd
```

My passwd file looks like the following (login/passwords changed for security):

```
### This file is an example password file for svnserve.
### Its format is similar to that of svnserve.conf. As shown in the
### example below it contains one section labelled [users].
### The name and password for each user follow, one account per line.

[users]
# harry = harryssecret
# sally = sallyssecret
mike = passw0rd
jim = ex4mple
bob = an0th3r
andy = 1more
```

For some reason though, I can still access my repo with a browser without logging in.  I've restarted my httpd server and I'm running on AWS (Linux).

Anyone have any clue what I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

svnserve is running, as demonstrated here:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ ps -ef | grep svnserve
ec2-user  8083     1  0 07:03 ?        00:00:00 svnserve -d --foreground -r /home/svn/
ec2-user 13655 13603  0 16:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep svnserve
```

**SOLVED**

I'm an idiot: turns out the reason I THOUGHT it wasn't working was that TortiseSVN was caching my credentials without showing me that, so when I tried to connect via command line/terminal it actualyl prompted me for the login.  Changing my password in the passwd file (for the first line, which is what Tortise had cached) made Tortise prompt me for a new login -- I didn't even have to restart my server.

Apologies for the stupidity and thank you all for your help!

Comment: The configuration looks fine. Is the svnserve running?

Comment: It was working all along, I'm just an idiot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apache does not correlate with svnserve'd repository at all
2. Show init-script for running svnserve (you may use another conf and user-file)
3. Show output of `svn ls svn://URL/TO/REPO`

Comment: The last line demonstrated to me that it IS working, I just didn't realize it because TortiseSVN had cached my credentials and I never noticed.  Thank you for your help!